# Filter for specific values, but if it doesn't exist it should be clear

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I created procedures that always filter for specific criterion in Excel by VBA.
My Excel file download data from other database. After downloading, I need to Filter it to get this data. Thus, I created procedures which do it.
However, Sometime there is no data, because database was not updated, thus no data was downloaded. In that case, I do not have this criteria in my Filter. Thus, If there is data, Filter should be for "Check", if there is no data, this Filter should be clear. I was wondering about "If" function but I was not aware how to implement it.
My code is:

```
Sub Filter1_Overview()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("X")
    sh.AutoFilterMode = False
    sh.Range("A1:Y7").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Name" 'this line of code is good
    sh.Range("A1:Y7").AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="Check" 'I would like to modify it
    
End Sub
```

If I implement this code and there is no data for "Check" criteria, there will be blank cells, but I would like to have only Clear Filter. But, if there is data for "Check", data for "Check" criteria should be shown.
Do you have any ideas how to deal with it ? I would appreciate it if someone could instruct myself.

Comment: Use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to test if the criterion is present in your data?

Comment: Should we understand that the downloaded data have the string "Check" in the 18th column?

Comment: @BigBen, could you please tell more about it ? I am a beginner in VBA. Can you give me examples of using it ?

Comment: @faneduru yes I filter by this Check to obtain data, this is my one of string in the column

Comment: Then, you should use `If  WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("R:R"), "Check") > 0 then` make filtering...

Comment: @faneduru thank you for it, but could you please write code for "make filtering"?. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please, check the code I posted.

Comment: But, I would like to tell that first I would like to filter by Name (this line of code works properly), then I would like to Filter by Check provided that there is data as was previously mentioned. Did you consider it ?

Comment: If you need addressing to me, you should write below my answer, or tag me (@FaneDuru). Otherwise, I do not receive any notification... I understood that you only want checking the presence of "Check" criteria, which to prove that the database has been updated. Then to use the filter which you say it works. If you need the second filtering only if "Check" exists, why do not try using the solution posted by VBasic2008. Doesn't it do what you need, neither?

Comment: @FaneDuru  sorry for this. I will put your name. I used code from VBasic2008 but it doesn't work properly because "Run- time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error". Broadly speaking, I do not know why he used Offset property because Fields for these criterion are on the same row.. Do you have any idea how to deal with ?

Comment: Taking your codes into consideration, they filter for Name in the column I, but it does not filter for Check,  where  is on the column T..

Comment: Then, try testing my updated code... I adaprted the code to check for "Check" in column T;T, but your filter is targeting `Field:=18`, which is not T:T. It is R:R. So, I will adapt it for T:T (column 20)...

Comment: @FaneDuru thank you for your support and patience! I will create a new post, using this code and put images to show people what I would like to convey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Optional Second Filter

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Filter1_Overview()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X").Range("A1:Y7")
        .Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Name"
        If Application.CountIf(.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1) _
                .Offset(1, 17), "Check") > 0 Then
            .AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="Check"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your support, unfortunately it doesn't work. I have "Run-time error 1004: Application- defined or object defined error". Could you please tell me why you use resize and offset methods? These cells are on the same row

Comment: Which line throws the error? I'm using `Resize` to not include the header in the `CountIf` and I'm using `Offset` to use `CountIf` only in column `18` (`"R"`).

Comment: In your code you are using column `18` which is column `R`, and now, in your comments, you are saying column `T`, which is column `20`. You should replace `18` with `20` and `17` with `19` in my code. Or replace `18` with `20` in your question and I will adjust accordingly. But anyway, it should not throw an error.

Comment: In my code the `.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)` resizes the range `A1:Y7` to `A1:A6`. Then the `.Offset(1, 17)` offsets the range `A1:A6` to `R2:R7` which is then used in `CountIf`.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, but it is a bit complicated for me on my stage. I would like to simply Filter for particular Name in the column I called "Name", then If I have in the column T called Check Filter for Check, it will be filtered, otherwise, I would like to have only Name and no filter in the column T. What do you think? is it possible to do it?

Comment: Could you post a link to a copy of your workbook, e.g. `Google Drive`...? I mean, the code is working on my end. I can't think of any reason why it should not work for you. You still haven't answered which line throws the error and you haven't reported back if you have tried the code after replacing `17` with `19` and `18` with `20`.

Comment: thank you for your patience and support!. Normally in the column I there must be always filtered for Name and it works. In the column T I have only 3 filters for example "A", "Check" and "B". Thus, I would like to have always Filter for Name, then for "Check" in the column I and T respectively. After refreshing sometimes I do not have information for "Check", thus on the column I I have only "A" and "B" Filters. Therefore, If I don't have "Check" filter in the Column T, I would like to have only as always on the column I "Name", then "A" and "B" on the column T.

Comment: It is the outcome which I would like to achieve.

Comment: Very funny. Column `I` is column `9`, and not column `7` which is column `G`. So additionally change `7` to `9`. All in all, replace `7, 17 and 18` with `9, 19 and 20` in my code.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my misunderstanding, but I work on the range of C7:AW7, and focus on the 7 and 18 columns. Your code does not work. The main issue is to make filter for "Check", on the column 18, if it exists. If no, it should not be Filter for this. Running these codes, even if there is no 'Check', it puts Filter.

Comment: thank you for your support and patience! I will create a new post, using this code and put images to show people what I would like to convey

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub Filter1_Overview()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("X")
    sh.AutoFilterMode = False
    sh.Range("A1:Y7").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Name" 'this line of code is good
    If  WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("T:T"), "Check") > 0 then
       sh.Range("A1:Y7").AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="Check" 
    end if    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your support and your code. Your code works properly, but I have one issue. In the column T I have a few filters for example Check, Ok and Ok Complete. Thus, your code works properly provided that I have in the Filter "Check", in the column T, but if I have only Ok and Ok Complete, this code runs and it makes troubles.. What Should I do for your code to run this code provided that I have only "Check" in the Filter. Otherwise, it should only filter for Name. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @lukasz93: I will be able to help only if I would understand what you need, but I must confess I don't... I do not understand anything about the "OK and OK Complete" part. Do you mean that, even if there are not "Check" in column T:T, when that two string exists the filter works? It shouldn't if `CountA` = 0. If do you mean something different, please better describe where the problem is and in which circumstances it appears...

Comment: thank you for your patience and support!. Normally in the column I there must be always filtered for Name and it works. In the column T I have only 3 filters for example "A", "Check" and "B". Thus, I would like to have always Filter for Name, then for "Check" in the column I and T respectively. After refreshing sometimes I do not have information for "Check", thus on the column I I have only "A" and "B" Filters. Therefore, If I don't have "Check" filter in the Column T, I would like to have only as always on the column I "Name", then "A" and "B" on the column T.

Comment: your code works, but if I don't have on the column T "Check", it appears Blank Cells with filtering for "Name" and it does not filter for A and B, do you understand me? If no, I will prepare Google worksheets.

Comment: @lukasz93: I am afraid you do not know what you want, no offence... When did you talk about "three filters"? Do you come now asking for filter by "Check" in column I:I? Did you asked about it and I missed the point? "After refreshing sometimes I do not have information for "Check", thus on the column I I have only "A" and "B" Filters." has no meaning for me. I do not understand anything! I wish you a good day!

Comment: Filters - it means Data, there is data for A,B, Check in cells respectively and after refreshing sometimes I don't have this data in cells. As you normally make Filter in an Excel you have some data and you put Filter to select it. Thus one of data is A,B or Check it my case.

Comment: @lukasz93: Are you able to refer at your question when talking about all these things? Anyhow, my last try: Do you want the code **in case of "Check" existence in column T:T, to filter by three criterion: "Check", "A" and "B"?**. If not I am not able to get you, sorry...

Comment: In case of "Check" existence in column T:T, to filter by one criteria: "Check". But, If it doesn't exist , to filter by only two criterion "A" an "B". Do you understand me ? is it possible to do ?

Comment: but, could you please create procedure which you meant from your comment. Perhaps I will try doing it and it will be the same like I thought. Perhaps, I could not explain it. Sorry.

Comment: @lukasz93: Definitely, not! I never work if I do not understand what is to be done.

Comment: The main issue is that your code runs and put Filter in my Excel Sheet when there is no data for "Check".

Comment: @lukasz93: It puts filter **exactly where you requested**. In column T:T.

Comment: I agree with you, but it puts everytime this Filter even if there is no "Check" criteria in this column. It seems that "function if" does not work properly. I would like to have Filter for the column T:T in the "Check" criteria only if Check criteria exists. Otherwise, it should be only for "Name" and leave column T:T out.